# Podio API Use Case - Please Advise

Tags: podio

I'm running software (Software A) on our local server that has a number of contacts (ie, Name, Address, Phone, etc).

Using the API from 'Software A', I'm looking to retrieve these contacts (ie, Name, Address, Phone, etc) and POST these contacts in my Podio workspace via Podio API.

My question is: What Operations should my developer be using with Podio API? I'm thinking the "Get Contacts" operation?
[Operations Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpYMi.png)

I ask because I noticed many of these operations under "Contacts" say "This operation is deprecated and will be removed soon."
[Deprecated Alert Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BYJf.png)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't want Contacts

That will retrieve your employees (the "members" that you pay-per-seat with your Podio subscription)

Contacts is becoming renamed as "Members" over time inside Podio, to make the distinction clearer.

The API you want to work with is "Items"

https://developers.podio.com/doc/items

This way you can edit and move data in and out from the "Podio App" you created for your Address Book storage (or perhaps you named this App as "Contacts", the label doesn't really matter)\

The "Address Book" app that you created will have an AppID which you can find by going to that app inside Podio, click the Wrench icon, then click Developer and you will see a field named:  App ID for Address Book (or whatever your app is called)

This App ID is an 8 digit number, and you want to use the App ID to retrieve/edit unique Items (unique records, like for each person) from your Address Book app.